# Setting DataGrid MaxHeight property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

```
<UserControl x:Class="DDCUI.CommDiagnosisWPFCtrl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="950" Width="300">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="300" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="DGComm" CanUserResizeColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedCellsChanged="DGComm_SelectedCellsChanged">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="No." Binding="{Binding Number}" Width="0.1*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Time}" Width="0.1*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Protocol" Binding="{Binding Protocol}" Width="0.15*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Source" Binding="{Binding Source}" Width="0.15*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Destination" Binding="{Binding Destination}" Width="0.15*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data" Binding="{Binding Data}" Width="0.5*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Top" MinHeight="200" Name="TreeViewDecode"/>
        <RichTextBox Name="RtbHexCode"/>

    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

For some reason, MaxHeight property of the DataGrid is not working. That is, whenever I bind a large table to it, it always overflows and hides the RichTextBox and TreeView (When in reality it shouldn't extend beyond 600 pixels and show a vertical scroll bar).

Also DataGrid doesn't show horizontal scroll bar.

How can I fix this issue?

Edit: Updated code. The MaxHeight property works now but horizontal scrollbar doesnt show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your DataGrid

```
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```

Also replace the StackPanel with a DockPanel or a Grid. StackPanel is not a constrained container.

Answer (score 0):

Height of your Window must be atleast 950  or set the MaxHeight of your Datagrid equal to 450 or set SizeToContent of your Window equal to WidthAndHeight. I hope this will help.